# Is there a way to use Ion-Refresher in a element in Ion-Content without pulling down all other content on the page?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use Ion Refresher in a list that sits within a Ion Content. I want to pull down just this list, but using Ion Refresher as directed in the documentation causes the entire page to be moved down, which doesn't make sense in this situation. How do you separate the relevant area in Ionic V4?

This is the list I am using.

```
<ion-content class="scroll-inner" *ngIf="platform.is('mobile') && transactions?.length > 0" scrollY="true">
        <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)"></ion-refresher>
        <ion-virtual-scroll no-margin no-padding [items]="transactions">
          <ion-item class="transaction" *virtualItem="let t">
            <ion-col size="4" size-xs="3" text-center>{{formatDate(t.timestamp)}}</ion-col>
            <ion-col size="4" size-xs="5" text-left>{{t.description}}</ion-col>
            <ion-col size="4" no-padding size-xs="2" text-center>{{t.fee ? (t.fee | currency) : '---'}}</ion-col>
            <ion-col size="4" no-padding size-xs="2" text-center [ngStyle]="t.amount === 0 && {'color': 'black'} ||
            t.amount > 0 && {'color': 'green'} ||
            t.amount < 0 && {'color': 'red'}">{{t.amount | currency}}</ion-col>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-virtual-scroll>
      </ion-content>
```

This code block is a component within a page that is wrapped with `<ion-content></ion-content>`

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to nest by using two ion-content:

```
<ion-content>
  <!-- other code -->

  <ion-content style="max-height: calc(100% - 220px);">
    <ion-refresher
      slot="fixed"
      (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)"
      style="position: relative;"
    >
      <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
      <ion-list lines="none">
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of List">
          {{item.name}}
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-refresher>
  </ion-content>

</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem, which happens and all the content inside your  will be pulled down. The best way is to place the ion-refresh inside the ion-content that will want the animation to go down.